# Gutenberg custom image block, alt text not showing in preview

Tags: reactjs, gutenberg-blocks

Trying to get alt text to render from a gutenberg custom image block. I can see the alt text when I inspect from the editor, but not from the preview. Need to see alt text in the preview and live versions. Thanks for any help.

Sorry for all of the code. The details are in the code.

edit.js

```
export default function Edit({ attributes, clientId, setAttributes }) {
    const [block, setBlock] = useState();
    const { action, url, newtab, popup, atts, alt} = attributes;
    const blockRef = useCallback(node=>{ setBlock(node); },[]);
    const blockProps = useBlockProps({ref:blockRef});
    const [linkModal, editLink] = useState(false);
    const dataAttributes = false;
    const actionOptions = [
        { value: '', label: 'Select Action' },
        { value: 'link', label: 'Link' },
        { value: 'document', label: 'Document' },
        { value: 'popup', label: 'Popup' }
    ]
    const options = (type, label = 'Select') => {
        const attributes = { order: 'asc', orderby: 'title', post_status: 'publish', 'per_page': -1 };
        const data = useSelect((select) => { return select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'smarttouch_'+type, attributes); });
        let options = [];
        if(data) { options.push({ value: '', label}); data.forEach(i=>{ options.push({ value: i.id.toString(), label: i.title.rendered }); }); }
        else { options.push({ value: '', label: 'Loading...'}); }
        return options;
    }
    const popupOptions = options('popup');
    const [attsList, setAttsList] = useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(!atts) return;
        if(!linkModal) return;
        window.attsList = atts;
    },[linkModal,atts]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(!popup) return;
        fetch('/wp-json/smarttouch/popup/'+popup).then(r=>r.json()).then((p) => {
            let attslist = p.post_content.match(/\[\[[^\]]+\]\]/g);
            attslist.forEach((att,i)=>{ att = att.replace(/[\[|\]]/g,''); attslist[i] = att; });
            setAttsList(attslist);
        });
    },[popup]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        resp.link.action = action;
        resp.link.url = url;
        resp.link.alt = alt;
        resp.link.newtab = newtab;
        resp.link.popup = popup;
        resp.link.atts = atts;
        updateImage();
    },[action, url, newtab, popup, atts, alt]);
    if((action=='document')&&(!newtab)) setAttributes({newtab:true});
    let { resp } = attributes;
    const kitten = 'https://placekitten.com/1280/720?image='+Math.floor(Math.sin(parseInt(clientId.replace(/[^0-9]/,'')))*8+8);
    resp = lodash.merge({
        desktop: { url: kitten, alt:'Placeholder Kitten',caption:'Placeholder Kitten (For Position Only)', ratio: 56.25, focalx: 0.5, focaly: 0.5, scale: 1, fit: 'cover' },
        tablet: { },
        mobile: { },
        svg: { colorMode: 'default', color: '#000' },
        link: {}
    }, JSON.parse(resp));
    const disp = resp[document.preview];
    const [ getResp, setResp] = useState();
    const ratios = [
        { value: '', label: 'Quick Set Ratio'},
        { value: '', label: 'Auto' },
        { value: '25', label: '4:1'},
        { value: '33.33', label: '3:1'},
        { value: '50', label: '2:1'},
        { value: '56.25', label: '16:9'},
        { value: '66.66', label: '2:3'},
        { value: '75', label: '3:4'},
        { value: '100', label: '1:1'},
        { value: '133.33', label: '4:3'},
        { value: '150', label: '3:2'},
        { value: '177', label: '9:16'},
        { value: '200', label: '1:2'}
    ];
    const fits = [
        { value: 'cover', label: 'Cover'},
        { value: 'contain', label: 'Contain'},
        { value: 'scale-down', label: 'Scale Down'},
        { value: 'fill', label: 'Stretch'}
    ];
    const svgColorModes = [
        { value: 'default', label: 'Keep SVG Colors' },
        { value: 'css', label: 'Use Theme CSS Color' },
        { value: 'select', label: 'Select Color' }
    ];
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(!block) return;
        const figure = block.querySelector('figure');
        const img = disp.url||resp.desktop.url;
        const prevFigure = figure.innerHTML;
        figure.style.setProperty('--focalx', (disp.focalx||resp.desktop.focalx)*100+'%');
        figure.style.setProperty('--focaly', (disp.focaly||resp.desktop.focaly)*100+'%');
        figure.style.setProperty('--scale', disp.scale||resp.desktop.scale);
        figure.style.setProperty('--fit', disp.fit||resp.desktop.fit||'cover');
        let ratio = disp.ratio||resp.desktop.ratio;
        if(ratio=='auto') {
            let i = document.createElement('img');
            i.onload = () => {
                disp.ratio = Math.floor(i.height / i.width * 10000) / 100;
                console.log('Save To Update Image Ratio');
                updateImage();
            }
            i.src = img;
        }
        figure.style.setProperty('--ratio', ratio+'%');
        if(img.split('.').pop()=='svg') {
            fetch(img).then(res=>res.text()).then((svg)=>{
                svg = svg.replace(/<\?xml[^\?]*\?>/,'');
                svg = svg.replace(/<!--[\s\S]*?-->\r?\n?/g,'');
                if(resp.svg.colorMode!=='default') {
                    svg = svg.replace(/\#[a-f0-9A-F]{3,6}/g,'currentColor');
                    if(svg.search(/currentColor/)<0) svg = svg.replace(/(<svg.*?>)(.*)<\/svg>/gs,'$1<g fill="currentColor">$2</g></svg>');
                }
                if(disp.ratio=='auto') {
                    const svgDom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(svg,'image/svg+xml').firstChild;
                    let v = svgDom.getAttribute('viewBox');
                    if(v) { v = v.split(' '); figure.paddingBottom = ((v[3] - v[1]) / (v[2] - v[0])) * 100 + '%'; }
                }
                if(prevFigure!=svg) figure.innerHTML = svg;
                if(resp.svg.colorMode=='select') { figure.querySelector('svg').setAttribute('color', resp.svg.color); }
            });
        } else {
            const newFigure = '<img src="'+img+'" alt="'+resp.desktop.alt+'">';
            if(prevFigure!=newFigure) figure.innerHTML = newFigure;
        }
        figure.classList.add('loaded');
    },[getResp]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        setResp(LZUTF8.compress(JSON.stringify(resp),{outputEncoding:'Base64'}));
    },[block]);
    const updateImage = () => {
        setAttributes({resp:JSON.stringify(resp)});
        setResp(LZUTF8.compress(JSON.stringify(resp),{outputEncoding:'Base64'}));
    };
    document.onpreview[clientId] = () => {
        setResp(LZUTF8.compress(JSON.stringify(resp),{outputEncoding:'Base64'}));
    }
    
    return (
        <>
            <InspectorControls>
                <PanelBody initialOpen={true}>
                    {(~(resp[document.preview.url]||resp.desktop.url).indexOf('.svg')) && (
                        <div class="squareImage"><img src={disp.url||resp.desktop.url} /></div>
                    )||(
                        <>
                            <FocalPointPicker
                                url={disp.url||resp.desktop.url}
                                dimensions={{width:disp.width,height:disp.height}}
                                value={{x:disp.focalx,y:disp.focaly}}
                                onDrag={focalPoint => {
                                    const figure = block.querySelector('figure');
                                    figure.style.setProperty('--focalx',focalPoint.x*100+'%');
                                    figure.style.setProperty('--focaly',focalPoint.y*100+'%');
                                }}
                                onChange={focalPoint => {
                                    disp.focalx = focalPoint.x;
                                    disp.focaly = focalPoint.y;
                                    updateImage();
                                }}
                            />
                            <RangeControl renderTooltipContent={()=>{ return Math.round(disp.scale*100)+'%';}} step={0.01} withInputField={false} min={0.5} max={2} value={disp.scale} onChange={scale=>{ disp.scale = scale; updateImage(); }} />
                        </>
                    )}
                    <div className="flex">
                        {(document.preview=='desktop')&&(
                            <MediaUpload className="block" value={resp.desktop.id||false} allowedTypes={['image/jpeg','image/png','image/svg+xml']} onSelect={(media)=>{
                                if(media.id!=resp.desktop.id) {
                                    resp.desktop.id = media.id; delete resp.tablet.id; delete resp.mobile.id;
                                    resp.desktop.url = media.url.replace(location.origin,''); delete resp.tablet.url; delete resp.mobile.url;
                                    resp.desktop.alt = media.alt;
                                    resp.desktop.caption = media.caption;
                                    resp.desktop.focalx = 0.5; delete resp.tablet.focalx; delete resp.mobile.focalx;
                                    resp.desktop.focaly = 0.5; delete resp.tablet.focaly; delete resp.mobile.focaly;
                                    resp.desktop.scale = 1; delete resp.tablet.scale; delete resp.mobile.scale;
                                    if(!resp.desktop.ratio) resp.desktop.ratio = Math.floor(media.height / media.width * 10000) / 100; delete resp.tablet.ratio; delete resp.mobile.ratio;
                                    updateImage();
                                }
                            }} render={({open})=>(<Button isPrimary={true} onClick={open}><Dashicon icon={(resp.desktop.id||false)?'format-image':'upload'} /> {(resp.desktop.id||false)?'UPDATE':'UPLOAD'} IMAGE</Button>)} />
                        )}              
                        {(document.preview!='desktop')&&(
                            <MediaUpload className="block" value={disp.id||resp.desktop.id} allowedTypes={['image/jpeg','image/png','image/svg+xml']} onSelect={(media)=>{
                                if(media.id!=disp.id) {
                                    disp.id = media.id;
                                    disp.alt = media.alt;
                                    disp.url = media.url.replace(location.origin,'');
                                    disp.focalx = 0.5;
                                    disp.focaly = 0.5;
                                    disp.scale = 1;
                                    if(!disp.ratio) disp.ratio = Math.floor(media.height / media.width * 10000) / 100;
                                    updateImage();
                                }
                            }} render={({open})=>(<Button isSecondary={true} onClick={open}><Dashicon icon={document.preview=='mobile'?'smartphone':document.preview} /> CHANGE {document.preview.toUpperCase()} IMAGE</Button>)} />
                        )}
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex">
                        <SelectControl label="Ratio" options={ratios} value="" onChange={ratio=>{
                            if(!ratio) {
                                let img = document.createElement('img');
                                img.onload = () => {
                                    disp.ratio = Math.floor(img.height / img.width * 10000) / 100;
                                    updateImage();
                                }
                                img.src = disp.url||resp.desktop.url;
                            } else {
                                disp.ratio = ratio;
                                updateImage();
                            }
                        }} />
                        <SelectControl label="Fit" options={fits} value={disp.fit||resp.desktop.fit} onChange={fit=>{ disp.fit = fit; updateImage(); }} />
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex">
                        <RangeControl renderTooltipContent={()=>{ return (disp.ratio||resp.desktop.ratio)+'%'; }} step={1} withInputField={false} min={0} max={100} value={+(disp.ratio||resp.desktop.ratio)} onChange={ratio=>{disp.ratio = ratio; updateImage(); }} />
                    </div>
                    {(~(disp.url||resp.desktop.url).indexOf('.svg')) && (
                        <>
                            <SelectControl label="SVG Color Mode" options={svgColorModes} value={resp.svg.colorMode} onChange={e=>{ resp.svg.colorMode = e; updateImage(); }} />
                            {(resp.svg.colorMode=='select') && (
                                <ColorPaletteControl value={resp.svg.color} onChange={(e)=>{ resp.svg.color = e; updateImage(); }} />
                            ) || ''}
                        </>
                    ) || ''}
                    <div class="flex">
                        <Button name="link" variant="primary" title="Link" icon="edit-large" onClick={e=>editLink(true)}>Edit Link Action</Button>
                    </div>
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>
            <div { ...blockProps }>
                <figure className="ratio" data-resp={getResp}></figure>
            </div>
            {linkModal&&(<>
                <Modal title={"Button Action"} onRequestClose={e=>{if(e.type=='click') editLink(false); }} isDismissible={true}>
                    <div className="cta-config">
                        <div className="flex">
                            <SelectControl help={"Click Through Action"} options={actionOptions} value={action}
                                onChange={e=>{ setAttributes({action: e}); }}  __nextHasNoMarginBottom />
                            {(action=='popup')&&(
                                <SelectControl help="Popup" options={popupOptions} value={popup}
                                    onChange={e=>{ setAttributes({popup: e, newtab: false}); }}  __nextHasNoMarginBottom />
                            )}
                        </div>
                        {(action=='link')&&(
                            <LinkControl
                                value={{url: url, opensInNewTab: newtab}}
                                onChange={({ url: url = '', opensInNewTab: opensInNewTab}) => {
                                    setAttributes({url, newtab: opensInNewTab });
                                }}
                                onRemove={(e)=>{
                                    setAttributes({url:'', newtab:false});
                                }}
                            />
                        )}
                        {(action=='document')&&(
                            <MediaUpload
                                multiple={false}
                                gallery={false}
                                allowedTypes={[
                                    'application/pdf',
                                    'application/msword',
                                    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                                    'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                                    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                                    'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
                                    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
                                    'text/csv',
                                    'text/plain',
                                    'application/rtf',
                                    'application/zip'
                                ]}
                                onSelect={(doc) => { setAttributes({ url: doc.url.replace(location.origin,''), newtab: true }) }}
                                render={ ({open}) => { return <div className="uploadDoc"><Button icon="upload" variant="primary" onClick={e=>open()}>{url?'Change':'Upload'} Document</Button><span>{url}</span></div> }}
                            />
                        )}
                        {attsList&&(
                        <div>
                            <label className="dataLabel" onClick={e=>{e.target.classList.toggle('active')}}>Requested Data Attributes</label>
                            <div className="data">
                                <label>ATTRIBUTE</label>
                                <label>SET VALUE</label>
                                {attsList.map((key, i) => (<>
                                    <label>{"[["+key+"]]"}</label>
                                    <div><input type="text" value={atts[key]||''} onChange={e=>{atts[key]=e.target.value;setAttributes({atts: {...atts}})}}/></div>
                                </>))}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        )}
                        {action&&(
                            <div class="flex">
                                {['link','anchor','document'].includes(action)&&(
                                    <a className="cta-test" href={url} target="_blank">TEST LINK</a>
                                )}
                                {(action=='popup')&&(
                                    <a className="cta-test" onClick={e=>{openPopup(popup,[],(base)=>{
                                        processAccordians(base);
                                        processButtons(base);
                                        processForms(base);
                                        processGalleries(base);
                                        processHomes(base);
                                        processImages(base);
                                        processSlides(base);
                                        processTabs(base);
                                        processConditions(base);
                                    })}}>TEST LINK</a>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </Modal>
            </>)||''}
        </>
    );
}
```

save.js

```
export default function save({ attributes }) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
    let { resp, alt } = attributes;
    
    const respData = LZUTF8.compress(resp,{outputEncoding:'Base64'})
    return (
        <div { ...blockProps }>
            <figure className="ratio" data-resp={respData}>
                <img src="#" alt={alt} />
            </figure>
        </div>
    );
}
```

block.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "smarttouch/image",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Image",
    "category": "smarttouch",
    "description": "Advanced image block",
    "textdomain": "image",
    "editorScript": "file:../../build/image.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:../../build/image.css",
    "supports": {
        "html": false,
        "anchor": false,
        "align": ["wide","full"],
        "lock": false
    },
    "attributes": {
        "resp": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "{}"
        },
        "alt": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "Alt Text",
            "source": "attribute",
            "selector": "figure img",
            "attribute": "alt"
          },
        "svgColorMode": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "default"
        },
        "svgColor": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "#000"
        },
        "atts": { "type": "object", "default": {} },
        "label": { "type": "string" },
        "action": { "type": "string" },
        "url": { "type": "string" },
        "newtab": { "type": "boolean" },
        "popup": { "type": "string" }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not showing"?

Comment: When I go to the preview and inspect, alt text is not in the image tag. It appears when I inspect in the Gutenberg code editor, but not in preview.

Answer (score 0):

I see. Usually when something like this happens to me, it is because the attribute type is not the same as I am actually passing it. So in your example the attribute "alt" should be of type "string", which it is. So that can not be the problem.

Try saving it into the block storage itsself, instead of getting it from the DOM element:

```
      "alt": {
        "type": "string",
        "default": "Alt Text"
      },
```